# On passing prepareForSegue , how do I pass my model object to my VC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

My prepareForSegue code looks like this :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "ShowVerse" {

        let pageDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PageViewController

        // Get the cell that generated this segue.
        if let selectedPageCell = sender as? PageTableViewCell {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedPageCell)!
            let selectedPage = pages[indexPath.row]
            pageDetailViewController.page = selectedPage
        }
    }

}
```

However, this line :

```
let selectedPageCell = sender as? PageTableViewCell
```

returns `nil`, and thus so, no information is passed to the ViewController.

How can I determine why this returns `nil`? And ultimately, how can I successfully assign selectedPageCell to my sender as PageTableViewCell.

My **TableViewCell.swift** :

```
import UIKit

class PageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var chapter: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var verse: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

[I'm basing my app off of this Apple Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH9-SW1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you really need here is the index of the selected row - so you could have that as a class-level variable, and assign it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Here's an outline of the code - with all sorts of assumptions about your class names

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    var selectedIndexPathRow = -1

    ... more code ...

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        selectedIndexPathRow = indexPath.row
    }


    ... more code ...

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
    {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowVerse" 
        {
            if selectedIndexPathRow != -1 // default value to show that something has been selected 
            {
                pageDetailViewController.page = pages[selectedIndexPathRow]
            }
        }
    }

... more code ...

}
```

Comment: If I did pass this info in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I wouldn't have access to the `segue` variable. But perhaps, I don't need that? And I could just put all the instantiation info in that method exclusively and just not use the method `prepareForSegue` . Sorry, I'm a complete newb to iOS/Swift/Obj-C :D

Comment: There's no problem with tracking the currently selected row, and only using it when you need to - in the `prepareForSegue` in this case.

Comment: Are you saying, put `selectedIndexPathRow` as a variable in my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, and then I'll be able to retrieve that variable in my `prepareForSegue` method? I'm not entirely sure how to write that. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you .Replace your code with below code .

you need to replace (sender: AnyObject?) to (sender: AnyObject!) and (sender  as? PageTableViewCell) to (sender  as PageTableViewCell)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

if segue.identifier == "ShowVerse" {

    let pageDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? PageViewController

    // Get the cell that generated this segue.
    if let selectedPageCell = sender as? PageTableViewCell {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedPageCell)!
        let selectedPage = pages[indexPath.row]
        pageDetailViewController.page = selectedPage
    }
}}
```

Happy coding .Provide your feedback.